# Possible Causes of OpenGL Performance Degradation Over Time

Tags: c++, opengl

So I was working on my OpenGL engine today and I noticed that if I leave it running for ~a minute and a half I start to experience some significant framerate drops. The first thing I did was make sure that there were no OpenGL allocations every frame. After both a code check and a separate profile application check I verified that I am not calling something like glGenBuffers() or something like that. Then I checked for possible issues with dynamic allocations per-frame. The code executed every frame is relatively large, but it doesn't seem like there are any dynamic allocations in the rendering pipeline. I checked the graph of memory usage and it doesn't even seem like I'm allocating any memory except for a little bit here and there, which I assume is coming from PhysX or OpenAL which are both in the program.

I thought that perhaps my CPU or GPU could be thermal throttling (I'm on a laptop). I ran the program until I experienced performance issues, closed it and immediately ran it again. The performance issues stopped once the application was re-run. What also strikes me as odd is that when I tab-out and tab back in the performance issues stop for a short period of time.

I'm a bit puzzled at what is happening here. I highly doubt it's a driver issue as other games work fine, although I haven't tried it on another computer. I've run some standard time-elapsed CPU profiling to try to figure out where the code was getting slow (I know these are generally unreliable because the GPU operates independently) and it just seems like anywhere that is touched by OpenGL just runs slower after the game is left running.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running an OpenGL debugger on your application. If you have an NVidia card you can use NSight for either visual studio or eclipse to visualise what the GPU is spending time on. Otherwise, [apitrace](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace) has solved a number of problems for me in the past.

Could your problem perhaps be related to an increasing number of draw calls?

Comment: I've run a profiler and basically all of my time is in glDrawArrays(), the other time is spent in swapping buffers which only takes a significant amount of time for Vsync. The profiler gives me a trace and I didn't notice any extra draw calls.

Comment: Does your scene have a lot of very small objects? In which case you can look into instancing, which allows batching of draw calls of the same object.

Comment: It's got 2 objects total, ~15 draw calls. I don't think instancing two objects would explain the degradation

Comment: Agreed, that volume is pretty small. How many polygons would you estimate them at?

Comment: It's Sponza and a plane, so about 250k

Comment: How about reducing the number of indices drawn to around 100? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138112/discussion-between-bartvbl-and-bluespud).